# Component state switching from function to render component

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am currently trying to use some data that I receive from an api in my render method. I am calling the function in my componentDidMount. Here is the function:

```
 getDataFromDb = () => {
        axios.get(this.props.urlFromParent + "GetCurrentPods/Device1")
            .then( (res) => {
                this.setState({
                    Pods : res.data
                })
                console.log(this.state.Pods)
            })
 };
```

and I am calling it in my render method like this

```
{console.log('hello'+ this.state.Pods)}
```

here is the console.log outputs:

```
hello[object Object]
Array [
Object {
    "ParentDeviceID": "Device1",
    "ParentDeviceIsActive": true,
    "PodIsActive": true,
    "PodLocation": 5,
    "PodType": 2,
    "__v": 0,
    "_id": "5d6bfe9c50a6c33006cbd6ac",
},
]
```

I cant figure out why the state is returning object Object in the render method.
Also i am receiving the error:
*Warning: Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within `render`). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state*
I'm not sure if this has anything to do with my problem. Thanks for any help.

Comment: please post your render method

Comment: render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                {console.log('hello'+ this.state.Pods)}   </View>
        );
    }

Comment: I have purposefully tabbed out everything because I was assuming it would be something else.

Comment: `{console.log('hello'+ this.state.Pods)}` will cast the Pods value into a string. When an object is converted to a string, it will look like `[object Object]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
console.log('hello'+ this.state.Pods)
```

The above line will convert the object to a string as you are concatenating the string "hello" with an object "this.state.Pods". You should use , or two console statements to logging hello and this.state.Pods differently.